Dynamics of a random stretch map
Notation: Here $S^1$ denotes the circle, which we view as the unit sphere in $\mathbb C$. We equip the circle with its natural length metric.
Let $\{\epsilon_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be iid uniformly distributed random variables on $[0, e]$ (with underlying probability space $\Omega$), and define the random maps $T_n: \Omega \times S^1 \to S^1$ by
$$T_n (e^{i \theta}) := e^{i \epsilon_n \theta}.$$
For $x \in S^1$, we write for short $D_n (x) := T_n \dots T_1 (x).$
Question: Is it true that for all $x, y \in S^1$, we have
$$d(D_n (x), D_n (y)) \to 0$$
almost surely?

what's $\Omega$?

@mathworker21 I assume the probability space the $\epsilon_i$ are defined on.

Doesn't follow this directly from $D_n(x)\leq,2^n,\prod \epsilon_i \to 0$  almost surely? (One has $a^n,\prod \epsilon_i \to 0$ for $a<e$.)

@KarlFabian I don't quite follow your sketch. $D_n (x)$ is an element of $S^1$.

That also related to your original $\min(|x-y|,|y-x|)$ metric which lives on$[0,1]$.

@Karl Fabian Sorry, that distance was a typo. It is a little bit ugly to write out explicitly anyhow, so I will just say it is the length metric.

But then better identify $S^1$ with $e^{i,\phi}$  and $2,\epsilon_k$ with $e^{i,\alpha_k}$ with $\alpha_k \in [0, 4,\pi]$. It then looks like there is no reason to believe that $D_n(x)$ and $D_n(y)$ should  converge a.e. because $\sum \alpha_k$ should still be equally distributed.

@NateRiver By Jensen, $E \log(2\epsilon_i) < 0$, so $D_n(x) \to 0$ by the LLN and the statement is trivially true, no?

@MartinHairer My apologies, I think the additive notation might be confusing people a bit. I will switch to using exponentials instead, one second.

@MartinHairer The notation has been corrected, though I think what you said might still work...

@MartinHairer You're right, its trivially true if the stretch factor is uniform between $0$ and $2$. I have changed it to be uniform between $0$ and $e$ instead, I think this is the nontrivial case.

I think what you're asking is not true.
There is an auxiliary process in the background (implicit in the comment of Martin Hairer and your modification of the question), which is the additive random walk:
$$
X_0=0;\ X_{n+1}=X_n+\log \epsilon_n(\omega).
$$
This random walk has zero drift, so $\limsup X_n=\infty$.
I'd prefer to describe your maps as taking place on $\Omega\times[0,1)$,
where $\Omega$ is the shift space $[0,e]^{\mathbb Z}$ equipped with the product of normalized Lebesgue measure. If a point $\omega\in\Omega$ is
written as $(\omega_n)_{n\in\mathbb Z}$, write $\sigma(\omega)$ for the shifted sequence: $\sigma(\omega)_n=\omega_{n+1}$.
the map $T$ is given by
$$
T(\omega,x)=(\sigma(\omega),\omega_0x\bmod 1).
$$
This is a skew product: the first coordinate is just the shift map, and the update rule in the second coordinate depends on the first coordinate. This map $T$ is called a random $\beta$-shift. They have been studied by Buzzi and others. Your $D_n(x)$'s are just the first coordinate of $T^n(x,\omega)$.
Define $n$ to be a reset time if $|D_n(x)-D_n(y)|\ge\frac 1{2e}$.
I claim that if $x\ne y$, either there exists $T$ such that $D_T(x)=D_T(y)$ (in which case $D_n(x)=D_n(y)$ for all $n\ge T$), or there are infinitely many reset times. Clearly for any $x$, there are countably many $y$ such that $D_n(x)=D_n(y)$ for some $n$. Assume $x$ and $y$ are such that $D_n(x)\ne D_n(y)$ for all $n$. We claim there are infinitely many reset times, and hence $|D_n(x)-D_n(y)|\not\to 0$.
To see this, let $m\in\mathbb N$.
Since $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\omega_m\cdots\omega_{n-1}=\infty$, there exists $n>m$ such that $\omega_m\cdots\omega_{n-1}|x-y|>\frac 1{2e}$.
Either $|D_n(x)-D_n(y)|=\omega_{m}\cdots\omega_{n-1}|x-y|$, in which case
$n$ is a reset time;
or there exists $m<j<n$ such that $\lfloor\omega_{j-1}D_{j-1}(x)\rfloor
\ne \lfloor \omega_{j-1}D_{j-1}(y)\rfloor$ (i.e. $D_{j-1}(x)$ and $D_{j-1}(y)$ lie on opposite sides of a discontinuity of $t\mapsto\epsilon_j t\bmod 1)$. In this second case if $0<|D_{j-1}(x)-D_{j-1}(y)|<\frac1{2e}$ then $|D_j(x)-D_j(y)|>\frac 12$, so there is a reset at time $j$, or if $|D_{j-1}(x)-D_{j-1}(y)|\ge \frac 1{2e}$, then there is a reset at time $j-1$.
In all cases, there is a reset time at or before $n$.

Interesting, I am not sure if I have understood your proof yet, but it checks out. Nice! Intuitively, what do random $\beta$-shifts represent?

Renyi started studying expansions of real numbers in non-integer bases. It turns out you can algorithmically write an $x\in[0,1]$ as $\sum d_n\beta^{-n}$ for any $\beta>1$, where the “digits” are allowed to take values in 0,…,$\lceil\beta\rceil-1$. This expansion may be non-unique, but there is a unique “greedy expansion”. That is what Renyi studied. It turns out it is closely related to the dynamics of $x\mapsto \beta x\bmod 1$. Renyi showed these dynamics could be studied using Ergodic theory.

More recently people generalized this to sequences of $\beta$. I’d say that this is more of a toy model than a serious way to understand the world.

Ah, thank you. I don't know anything about their physical significance, but in my opinion these are more than a serious way of studying the world of mathematics. Since I don't know the surrounding areas very well, I cannot say anything specific, but I am sure there are deep links to number theory, ergodic theory, harmonic analysis and fractals/geometric measure theory.

... in fact probably even probability theory. But if I knew what the deep link was, I would presumably already be writing a paper on it!
